# C# Bitmap Change Pixel color by doing XOR

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, bitmap, byte, drawing

I try to change RGB color using XOR of RGB. 
example: 
=> if value of R on some pixel is 5 = 101 
//Color pcolor = image.GetPixel(j, k);
=> then doing XOR with some byte 101 ^ 11111111 = 11111010
//R[x, w] = (byte) (R[x, w] ^ mykey[0]);
=> and replace R with result R=11111010=250 
//image.SetPixel(y, z, Color.FromArgb(A[y, z], R[y, z], G[y, z], B[y, z]));

but the problem is if i read again that result frame, R value that i was change before are not 250.

```
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;
```

---

```
VideoFileReader reader = new VideoFileReader();
reader.Open(@"E:\Video\Sample.MP4");
VideoFileWriter writer = new VideoFileWriter();
writer.Open(@"E:\Video\Result.MP4", reader.Width, reader.Height, reader.FrameRate, VideoCodec.MPEG4);
MyFunc(reader, writer)
```

---

```
public static void Myfunc(VideoFileReader reader, VideoFileWriter writer)
    {
    byte[] mykey = { 0xff, 0x55, 0x00 };
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(reader.Width, reader.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
    for (int i = 0; i<reader.FrameCount; i++)
    {
        Bitmap videoFrame = reader.ReadVideoFrame();
        image = videoFrame;
        byte[,] A = new byte[reader.Width, reader.Height];
        byte[,] R = new byte[reader.Width, reader.Height];
        byte[,] G = new byte[reader.Width, reader.Height];
        byte[,] B = new byte[reader.Width, reader.Height];
        for (int j = 0; j<reader.Width; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k<reader.Height; k++)
            {
                Color pcolor = image.GetPixel(j, k);
                A[j, k] = pcolor.A;
                R[j, k] = pcolor.R;
                G[j, k] = pcolor.G;
                B[j, k] = pcolor.B;
            }
        }

        for (int x = 0; x<reader.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w<reader.Height; w++)
            {
                R[x, w] = (byte) (R[x, w] ^ mykey[0]);
                G[x, w] = (byte) (G[x, w] ^ mykey[0]);
                B[x, w] = (byte) (B[x, w] ^ mykey[0]);
           }
        }

        for (int y = 0; y<reader.Width; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z<reader.Height; z++)
            {
                image.SetPixel(y, z, Color.FromArgb(A[y, z], R[y, z], G[y, z], B[y, z]));
            }
        }

        writer.WriteVideoFrame(image);
        videoFrame.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual code that you're using. The code you've posted won't compile.

Comment: @itsme86 that my actual code. i use ffmpeg C# library to read a frame of video.

Comment: I can tell it's not your actual code because you said it doesn't change the color, which implies that it runs, which means it compiles. Unless you've somehow added a property called `Lenght` to a byte array, it will not compile. If you don't post your actual code, we might end up spending time on code issues that don't actually exist.

Comment: @itsme86 ok sorry, i miss that part. lets make that `x % mykey.Length` (I wrote `mykey.Lenght` on question sorry) to 0.

Comment: I try with black and white video. first value of R is 0, and XOR with 255. result will be 255. after process done. and i read frame result R value change to 251. whether `writer.WriteVideoFrame(image)` function is changing the color value?.